# Moving nodes in background on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nodes

I really like the effect on http://whois.domaintools.com/ and want to integrate this in a project. After some digging on the internet I actually found a codepen! [www.codepen.io]/thewistedtaste/pen/GgrWLp.

I've been playing around with it for some time now and by changing the values I was able to adjust the circle radius, speed of animation, number of circles etc. However, I can't seem to find how to adjust the radius around the mouse in which the nodes are visible. Is it simply not possible or am I overlooking the right value?
Please give me some advice or helpful link. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius is determined by the `if/else` statement that begins at line 196 in the JS. Increase the values (`2000`, `20000`, etc.) to increase the range of which nodes highlight while moving your cursor.

```
for ( var i in points ) {
    // detect points in range
    if ( Math.abs( getDistance( target, points[ i ] ) ) < 2000 ) {
        points[ i ].active = 0.2;
        points[ i ].circle.active = 0.5;
    } else if ( Math.abs( getDistance( target, points[ i ] ) ) < 20000 ) {
        points[ i ].active = 0.1;
        points[ i ].circle.active = 0.3;
    } else...
```

Comment: How could I've missed that!! Thanks a lot, that did the trick.